# Prompt for username until name not found in file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I'm trying to grep a variable into a file but for some reason I can't.
Here's the code:

```
 while [[ $user ]]
                    do
                            read user
                            if grep -q "^${user}" date.txt; then
                            echo This user already exists 
                            read user
                    else
                            break
                            fi
                    done
```

If the user is not found it should break the while loop.But I can't make this work and I don't know why

Comment: Is `$user` set to something before it enters this code? If not, it would not even _enter_ the `while` loop.

Comment: Yes it is.Just before the while loop I have `read user`

Comment: And the first thing that happens in the loop is another `read user`. Does the code work if you enter the username at that second `read user` too?

Comment: I Had that line there before I added the `if` statemante.You are right ,i should delete that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are writing some form of validating input loop.

This is usually done in an infinite loop that you exit once valid input has been entered:

```
while true; do
    read data

    if data-is-valid; then
        break
    fi
done
```

In your case:

```
while true; do
    read -r -p 'Enter username: ' username

    if ! grep -q -e "^$username\>" date.txt; then
        break
    fi

    echo 'User already exists, try again' >&2
done
```

The `\>` pattern in the `grep` command ensures that a user `theo` does not match the user `theodore` in the `date.txt` file by requiring that the word ends directly after the string.